# Problems with transferFrom within a contract

Tags: erc-20, web3.py, transferfrom

I am playing around with this [repo](https://github.com/yosriady/continuous-token), more exactly with the ERC20ContinuousToken.sol contract. I am able to successfully run the truffle tests after connecting the project to Ganache, so I know that everything is fine with the repo.

When I'm testing out things in python however, I'm getting an annoying error. Here is part of my code:

```
acc0 = web3.eth.accounts[0]

txargs0 = {"from": acc0 }

erc20contract = web3.eth.contract(
address=tx_receipt.contractAddress,
abi=erc20_abi,
)

continuous_contract = web3.eth.contract(
address=tx_receipt.contractAddress,
abi=continuous_abi,
)

continuous_addr = tx_receipt["contractAddress"]

erc20contract.functions.approve(acc1, web3.toWei(4,'ether')).transact(txargs0)

print(web3.fromWei(erc20contract.functions.allowance(acc0, continuous_addr).call(txargs0),'ether'))

continuous_contract.functions.mint(web3.toWei(2,'ether')).transact(txargs0)
```

The last line of the code is throwing an ValueError and I have no idea why:

```
ValueError: {'message': 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Invalid inputs.', 'code': -32000, 'data': {'stack': 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Invalid inputs.\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:89:13)\n    at module.exports (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/gas/guestimation.js:142:32)', 'name': 'RuntimeError'}}
```

The mint function of the ERC20ContinuousToken contract requires uses transferFrom and requires an approval. The weird thing is that the repos tests also use the mint function and it works.

Within the ERC20ContinuousToken.test.js file we have these two lines:

```
await this.reserveToken.approve(this.continuousToken.address, depositAmount, { from: A });
const result = await this.continuousToken.mint(depositAmount, { from: A });
```

This part of the test passes. My python code, which does the same thing, returns an error. Can anyone help me figure out whats wrong with the python code?

Comment: Please share the relevant repo test (in plain text and within your question). Also what makes you think that the problem is with `transferFrom `?

Comment: @goodvibration here is the repo test https://github.com/yosriady/continuous-token/blob/master/test/js/ERC20ContinuousToken.test.js

I'm not sure if the problem is with transferFrom, but the error is occurring only after I'm trying to use the mint function from this contract https://github.com/yosriady/continuous-token/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20ContinuousToken.sol

Comment: What's not clear about **in plain text and within your question**?

Comment: I do not understand why when minting in the truffle tests, everything works fine, but when I am trying to mint continuous tokens in python, it's throwing an error. I am clearly doing something wrong in the python part.

Comment: Yeah you already explained that well in your question, but the relevant truffle test is still not there!!!

Comment: @goodvibration I edited the question. I mentioned the test file name, as well as the two lines where minting is done. That test works without a problem. Doing the same thing with the python snippet that I provided however, does not work, and I don't know why.

Comment: In the test - `approve(this.continuousToken.address,...)`, in your code - `approve(acc1, ...)`. Can you spot the difference?

Comment: I get the same error if I switch acc1 with the continuous contract address. I also edited the code so now it's with the continuous_addr instead of acc1.